# Как сделать, чтоб отмена работала отдельно в полях ввода

Tags: javascript

И снова здравствуйте..
Интересует, как сделать, чтоб при отмене или повторе(ctr+z, ctrl+shift+z) ввода, это работало только с полем в фокусе, а не отменялось по очереди всё, что было в остальных полях.

Я не прошу готового кода, просто не понимаю, в каком вообще направлении копать.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос...

Comment: Ну вот допустим у меня два поля ввода. Я в одном ввёл xxx, а во втором yyy. И когда я клкаю по первому и жму ctrl z, чтоб отменить, то спала текст сотрётся во втором, а потом уже в первом.

Comment: А мне нужно, чтоб отменялся ввод только в первом

Comment: Решение _"в лоб"_ - захват фокуса или наведения над элементом и обработка событий нажатия клавиш

Comment: Нет.. Это не пойдёт. Ведь если учитывать все действия, которые пользователь может совершить с текстом, то наверное понадобится целая библиотека.. Я тут подумал, а что, если использовать ифреймы место полей ввода? И в каждом выполнять document.execCommand("undo")